# Python Tkinter login GUI with database

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql, authentication, tkinter

I created a simple login program that works how I wanted them to work. I separated the GUI and database codes into two different python files. I named the files as *login.py* and *dbaseManip.py*. The **login.py** consist of Tkinter syntax and all stuff related to GUI. On the other hand, **dbaseManip.py** holds the database related syntax such as the connection and the queries.

**login.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk

import dbaseManip as db

class loginForm(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,*arags,**kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent

        self.parent.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",self.closing_window)

        window_width = 350
        window_height = 100
        screen_width = self.parent.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.parent.winfo_screenheight()

        x_position = int((screen_width/2) - (window_width/2))
        y_position = int((screen_height/2) - (window_height/2))

        self.parent.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(window_width,window_height,x_position,y_position))

        self.widgeter()

    def widgeter(self):
        self.ent_username = ttk.Entry(self.parent)
        self.ent_username.insert(0,"username")
        self.ent_username.bind("<FocusIn>",self.foc_in_username)
        self.ent_username.bind("<FocusOut>",self.foc_out_username)


        self.ent_password = ttk.Entry(self.parent)
        self.ent_password.insert(0,"password")
        self.ent_password.bind("<FocusIn>",self.foc_in_password)
        self.ent_password.bind("<FocusOut>",self.foc_out_password)

        btn_login = ttk.Button(self.parent,text="Login",command=self.submit)
        btn_exit = ttk.Button(self.parent,text="Exit",command=self.closing_window)

        self.ent_username.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3,sticky="nsew")
        self.ent_password.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=3,sticky="nsew")

        btn_login.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky="nsw")
        btn_exit.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky="nse")


    def foc_in_username(self, *args):
        if self.ent_username.get() == "username":
            self.ent_username.delete(0, tk.END)

    def foc_out_username(self,*args):
        if not self.ent_username.get():
            self.ent_username.insert(0,"username")

    def foc_in_password(self,*args):
        if self.ent_password.get() == "password":
            self.ent_password.delete(0,tk.END)
            self.ent_password.configure(show="*")

    def foc_out_password(self,*args):
        if not self.ent_password.get():
            self.ent_password.insert(0,"password")
            self.ent_password.configure(show="")

    def closing_window(self):
        answer = messagebox.askyesno("Exit","You want to exit the program?")
        if answer == True:
            self.parent.destroy()

    def submit(self):
        __verify = db.DatabaseManip(self.ent_username.get(),self.ent_password.get())
        __str_verify = str(__verify)
        if __str_verify == "correct":
            self.initialize_mainApplication()
        elif __str_verify is "incorrect":
            messagebox.showerror("Incorrect Password","You have entered incorrect password")
            # add deleter
        elif __str_verify == "notexist":
            messagebox.showerror("Username does not exist","The username you entered does not exist")


    def initialize_mainApplication(self):
        self.parent.destroy()
        self.parent = tk.Tk()
        self.mainApp = mainApplicaiton(self.parent)
        self.parent.mainloop()

class mainApplicaiton(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.parent = parent

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    loginForm(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

**dbaseManip.py**

```
import mysql.connector

class DatabaseManip():
    def __init__(self,username,password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        #
        # print(self.username)
        # print(self.password)

        self.dbaseInitializer()

    def dbaseInitializer(self):
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
            host="127.0.0.1",
            user="root",
            password="admin123",
            database="testdb"
        )

        self.myCursor = mydb.cursor()
        query_user_exists = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s)"
        self.myCursor.execute(query_user_exists,(self.username,))
        tuple_user_exists = self.myCursor.fetchone()
        total_user_exists = int(tuple_user_exists[0])

        if total_user_exists != 0:
            query_pass_validation = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = %s"
            self.myCursor.execute(query_pass_validation,(self.username,))
            __tuple_valid_pass = self.myCursor.fetchone()
            __password_validation = __tuple_valid_pass[0]

            if __password_validation == self.password:

                self.verdict = "correct"
            else:
                self.verdict = "incorrect"

        else:
            self.verdict = "notexist"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.verdict


    @property
    def username(self):
        return self.__username
    @username.setter
    def username(self,username):
        self.__username = username


    @property
    def password(self):
        return self.__password
    @password.setter
    def password(self,password):
        self.__password = password
```

This is how the system works:

1. The login form will pop up
2. After the user submitting their username and password, it will call the class DatabaseManip() that exists in dbaseManip.py.
3. The DatabaseManip Class will validate the user's account.
4. **HERE COMES MY PROBLEM** If the username does not exist in the database, it will assign a string "notexist" to a class variable called *verdict*. If the password is wrong, it will assign "incorrect". And lastly, if the validation is correct; it will assign "correct".
5. The verdict result (which is either "correct","incorrect" or "notexist") will be returned to the GUI class in **login.py** using the `__str__` method.
6. In the loginForm class, a conditional statement will determine if the verdict from the databaseManip class is either "correct","incorrect" or "notexist". If it is "correct", a new window will pop-up. On the other hand, if it is either "incorrect" or "notexist", it will show an error message.

I think my way of coding this is extremely bad in terms of security and integrity. I'm not confident in the "correct", "incorrect", and "notexit" part. I would like to ask for advice to make this program more secure and not as wacky as the current state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly I'd suggest following [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and/or using an auto-formatter like [black](https://github.com/psf/black), but if it's just you working on it
that is a bit less of an issue than if other people were involved.
Suffice to say, most code follows that and it usually gets flagged first
thing (because it's so noticeable).

Reading the code, is that all there is, you are able to log in via a
GUI?  Then I'd say first thing would probably be not to hardcode the
credentials to the database.  So what/how's this securing anything?  If
the program has the credentials ... and the program is being run by the
user who's authenticating ... what stops me from connecting directly to
the database?

---

Apart from that fundamental issue looks mostly okay, no SQL injection
since the `execute` will handle that.

`__` as prefix for the variable names is unnecessary and confusing.  I
can't see why it's there at all.

Actually, `SELECT password ...` ... the password's stored in plaintext?
Big no-no in anything used by other people.  Do not store passwords in
plaintext.

The properties at the end of `DatabaseManip` seem not very useful, in
Python there's no need for them unless you want to control what/how
values are stored in the object / how they're computed if they're not
stored at all.

The `__str__` method is there for what reason?  That's very much
confusing the responsibility of the class.  It would somewhat make sense
if it's being used interactively in a REPL, otherwise I can't see the
reason for having it.  Oh.  Oh now I see it.  Yeah, don't do that,
that's bad style.  How I'd expect things to go is something like this:

```
    def submit(self):
        result = db.DatabaseManip().check_credentials(self.ent_username,self.ent_password)
        if result == "correct":
            self.initialize_mainApplication()
        elif result == "incorrect":
            messagebox.showerror("Incorrect Password","You have entered incorrect password")
            # add deleter
        elif result == "notexist":
            messagebox.showerror("Username does not exist","The username you entered does not exist")
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Unexpected validation result","Validation of credentials failed unexpectedly with result".format(result))
```

So here: Validating is an action, a method.  The parameters of which
aren't part of the helper object, but method parameters.  The result is
still a string (try making this an enumeration, that's more "correct" in
a way as you really want to have a fixed set of possible results, not a
string that can contain basically anything.  Finally, the programmer
error case is handled too (the last `else`).

Also note that `... is "foo"` is *likely* incorrect, c.f.
`"foo" is "foobar"[0:3]`, [`is` does a check for object identity](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is-not), [not
equality](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-operator-python/)!  Not even numbers are same via `is` if they're not interned at
the same time:

```
1000000 == 1000000 # _always_ True

x = 1000000
y = 1000000
x is y # _probably_ False
```

Also `if x == True` can obviously be simplified to `if x`.

---

So it's not all bad, simply try and stay away from "stringly"-typed
things, use the language features as they're intended and have a goal
for what your security requirements are.  I've not gone into more detail
on the last bit simply because I still don't understand the intent
here.  Suffice to say like this it would only work if the user can't
exit the UI and open a shell / other means of executing code on the
machine (like in a kiosk configuration with limited access to
peripherals and the machine itself).  Or if the actual database access
was moved to a separate external service that (again) can't be
circumvented by the local user.